# How to replace values in pandas with column names

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-manipulation

I am trying to make a recommendation system using Last.fm data to recommend user songs a user will like to hear.

I am using NearestNeighbors Algorithm to predict feature songs user will like to hear.
I have made the model but problem I am facing is I am getting Integer values instead of the song names in the Pandas DataFrame.
This is a screenshot of what I am getting

[image]

Instead of numbers in the value section I want the song name in the dataset.
How do I achieve this.
This is what the output should look like:

[image]
Here is the link to my Ipython notebook: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/kartikjagdale/Last.fm-Song-Recommender/blob/master/Ipython%20Notebook/Last.Fm%20Song%20Recommeder.ipynb

and link to my github project: https://github.com/kartikjagdale/Last.fm-Song-Recommender/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataFrame.columns` is an `Index` object, which can be used as array.

You can use `pd.DataFrame(df.columns[model])` to get names, here is an example：

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 5, (10, 5)), columns=list("ABCDE"))
neigh = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=3)
neigh.fit(df.T) # Fit the data
model = neigh.kneighbors(df.T, return_distance=False)
pd.DataFrame(df.columns[model])
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked! I don't have a reputation to upvote but will upvote when I have get required reputation to upvote. Thank You!